# Flutter dependencies problems after upgrade

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies, flutter-intl, flutter-upgrade

My code was working without problem. After upgrading flutter, pug get is giving error:
[image]

But when I set intl to intl 0.17.0  , I got another error
[image]

How can I solve this. Is it possible to go back in the old version of flutter? Thanks

Comment: Have you checked  : https://pratikbutani.medium.com/flutter-2-upgrade-flutter-version-solving-failed-error-33ac1087cb6b

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be just remove the version from the dependencies which are causing error. And then run pub get it will automatically take the best version combination.
For example replace :-

```
intl: ^0.17.0
```

with

```
intl:
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try overriding the dependencies with:

```
dependencies:

  ...

dependency_overrides:
   #  intl: any
   intl: ^0.17.0-nullsafety.2
```

Try overriding with specific version to limit the problem.